# Binomial distribution vs Normal distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

It is often said that the normal distribution "approximates" the binomial distribution. What is the *precise* mathematical expression of this fact?

Comment: This might be useful: the [de Moivre–Laplace theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre–Laplace_theorem).

Comment: Large number theorem?

Comment: It has been many years. Would you consider deleting this question post? I assume you have already got your answer here or elsewhere and moved on.

Comment: Hello? Are you there? Please post an answer and "accept" it yourself (self-answering is encouraged on the site) or delete the question, otherwise it's clogging up the system.

Comment: Hi, yes, I have the precise answer now. I will post it soon. Thanks.